# OpenGL on Mac OS X for an iPhone developer

Tags: ios, macos, opengl

I'm looking for a good example of a basic OpenGL App for Mac OS X, but not too simple.

I have a good solid base of experience with iOS and objective-c, but I've never built a Mac OS X App.

All I've been able to find are super simple examples that do all the drawing and logic in drawRect: or overly complex examples with layers and layers of abstraction.  I don't want to use Glut, SDL, or any other 3rd party libs or engines.

I want to be able to drive a Game Loop and use CADisplayLink like I do on my iOS games.  I'd also rather not use .xib files because I like to understand what's going on and having that black box there hides too much for me, although I'd be happy to use it as a first step if it got me everything else (game loop, CADisplayLink, etc).

My iOS code creates it's OpenGL Views by hand, but there seems to be enough of a difference between iOS and OS X that I'm having trouble making heads or tails of it.  I just need to get a Window and an OpenGL view and be able to draw to that via the game loop.

Can someone point me to a good resource?  The Apples examples jump between to simple and too complex as does everything else I can find on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't answer to your questions. I always did use XIB files (a looong time ago, I too always wanted to re-invent the wheel, but now I'm lazy and prefer getting stuff done :p) and I never used display links.

What don't you like about overriding drawRect: ?

And the sample I used to get started with OpenGL was this one : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004501

Not too complicated, and simple enough to understand it (and it doesn't use any XIB, if I remember well :p)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what drawRect: is for, but it seems that is called by the OS when the window needs to be refreshed, but for a game with an always running game loop, that doesn't make sense.  Am I not understanding what drawRect: is?

Comment: Ah, yes you are correctly understanding, but if you take a look into the sample I linked, it simply creates a timer which will repetedly call the drawRect: method.
I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it works fine ^^ (at least in the sample, and for my little engine & editor ^^)

Comment: I spent the day hacking apart the example you linked to and I think I have everything working.  I don't know if it is the best way to do it, but it works for now.  Thanks again.